# $T$ is a diagonalizable linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$. Is every linear operator commuting with $T$ a polynomial of $T$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to answer this question

True or false?
$T$ is a diagonalizable linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$. Then every linear operator that commutes with $T$ is a polynomial of $T$.

I think the statement false but unable to find a counter example.
So any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false, at least when $\dim V > 1$: The identity transformation $id$ on $V$ (which is diagonalizable) commutes with every linear operator $V \to V$, but every polynomial in $id$ is a multiple of $id$; in particular, linear operators that are not multiples of $id$ commute with $id$ but are not polynomials in $id$.

Comment: I wonder why does it take this long to upvote a simple, correct answer like this one. +1

Comment: @Travis thank you for your help

Comment: You're welcome.